# Confidence interval for (unobserved) sample mean

Tags: estimation, prediction-interval

Suppose I take two samples, $a$ and $b$, from a population (or super population) but that I only observe $b$. However, I want to construct a confidence interval for $\bar{a}$, the average of the sample that I don't observe.

Now, a confidence interval that contains the population mean 95 percent of the time cannot also contain the sample mean, $\bar{a}$, 95 percent of the time unless the sample mean is always equal to the population mean, which it generally is not.

As best as I can tell, a confidence interval that covers $\bar{a}$ can be constructed as follows,

$$
\bar{b} \pm \cdot \sqrt{\frac{S_B}{n_B} \times 2}
$$

given sufficiently large samples. I want to prove that this in fact is the case.

As I've likely made some mistakes in notation above, here's a simple simulation to illustrate that one does, in fact, need to double the variance.

In case I wasn't clear enough above, I want a confidence interval that covers $\bar{a}$, not $E(\bar{A})$, 95 percent of the time.

```
set.seed(206)

func <- function(){
  
  A <- rnorm(500)
  B <- rnorm(500)
  
  ub_hi <- mean(B) + 1.96 * sqrt( var(B) / (n/2) )
  ub_lo <- mean(B) - 1.96 * sqrt( var(B) / (n/2) )
  
  unbiased <- ifelse(mean(A) <= ub_hi & mean(A) >= ub_lo, 1, 0)
  names(unbiased) <- "Single_Variance"
  
  b_hi <- mean(B) + 1.96 * sqrt( 2 * var(B) / (n/2) )
  b_lo <- mean(B) - 1.96 * sqrt( 2 * var(B) / (n/2) )
  
  biased <- ifelse(mean(A) <= b_hi & mean(A) >= b_lo, 1, 0)
  names(biased) <- "Double_Variance"
  
  return(list(unbiased, biased))
  
}
  
y <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) {unlist(func())}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>% 
  rowwise() 

mean(y$Single_Variance)
mean(y$Double_Variance)
```

My results are ~85 percent coverage for the single variance approach and ~95 percent coverage for the double variance approach.

**Note**

Thanks to the comments below, I have rewritten this question. The first version of this question included my argument that there is no unbiased estimator for $\bar{a}$ such that a bias terms appears that is equal in expectation to zero but that introduces additional variance in the estimator. I've removed this to focus more clearly on the question, how do you derive/prove the confidence interval for $\bar{a}$ that involves doubling the variance of $\bar{b}$.

Thanks to everyone for helping me to formulate this more clearly.

Comment: What are $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ in your question? Are those means of the samples $A$ and $B$? If yes, what you're saying is contradictory, because if those are two random samples from the same population you cannot “know” they differ, the opposite, you know they should be the same. Moreover, the title is misleading as there's no bias here.

Comment: Yes, but for a sufficiently small finite population, the mean of sample B will not equal the mean of sample A and the expectation of the mean of sample B will not equal a particular realization of the mean of sample B.

Comment: One of my questions is about terminology though. So perhaps you can set me straight here. Maybe I should write E(\bar{B}) \neq \bar{a} to indicate I'm interested in estimating a particular realization of \bar{A}.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with what you are describing. It only means that with smaller samples the estimates are less reliable, but not biased.

Comment: If you are interested in “particular realization” the question is like asking “if I throw two identical dice, how to calculate the result of one dice from another”—you can’t, both are *random*.

Comment: I get that the expectation of the mean of A equals the expectation of the mean of B. However, if I want to know the mean of a particularly realization of B, and I estimate that with the mean of A, then I have bias unless the mean of B happens to equal the expectations of the mean of B, no?

Comment: If I pretend that E(\bar{B}) = \bar{A}, then I won't get a confidence interval that covers \bar{A}. I have to double the variance. I can convince myself why but I'm having trouble formalizing this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with bias. If you throw two identical dice and get different results, it doesn't mean that either of the dice is “biased”.

Comment: Of course not. E(\bar{A}) and E(\bar{B}) are unbiased estimators for the population mean. That doesn't mean that E(\bar{B}) = \bar{A}. Would it be helpful if I added a simple simulation? Perhaps some of my notation is incorrect.

Comment: Does it make any difference if instead of two dice you throw ten and ten, and average the results in both groups? Would different results mean that one group was “biased”?

Comment: It would *really* help if you defined the exact quantity you want to estimate.

Comment: I want to estimate the realized mean of group A such that on repeated randomizations I can construct an confidence interval that will cover the realized mean of group A 95 percent of the time.

Comment: This would be the same as the mean of B, or the mean of the population.

Comment: @Tim I thought that would be the case, but my simulation seems to show most of the confidence intervals of $\bar B$ not containing $\bar A$. ```set.seed(2023);
N <- 100;
R <- 1000;
containment <- rep(1, R);
for (i in 1:R){;
  
  x <- rnorm(N);
  a <- x[1:5];
  b <- x[6:N];
  p <- t.test(b);
  
  if (mean(a) > p$conf.int[2]){;
    containment[i] <- 0;
  };
  
  if (mean(a) < p$conf.int[1]){;
    containment[i] <- 0;
  };
};
table(containment);```

Comment: @Dave they ought to contain the true mean, not the sample mean.

Comment: A confidence interval that contains the population mean 95 percent of the time cannot also contain the sample mean 95 percent of the time unless the sample mean is always equal to the population mean, which it generally is not. I want a confidence interval that covers the sample mean 95 percent of the time, i.e. the sample mean of A when I only observe B.

Comment: The question would be easier to understand if you said directly that you are interested in estimating an interval such that a new sample mean from the same population would be covered by it. The whole discussion about bias is misleading and wrong as there's no bias, just good old randomness.

Comment: @Tim, as I note in my original post, this is one of my questions. I mention some arguments for considering $E(\bar{B})$ an unbiased estimator, repeated sampling of both A and B, consistent, etc. but I can't get over the fact that $E(\bar{B}) \neq \bar{A}$. Perhaps you can explain where I'm confused here.

Comment: Maybe this is hard to imagine the way I've motivated it, but in a super-population framework, I take one sample, call it A. Then I can take a thousand additional samples from the same distribution, but the average of those additional samples will not equal the average of A. I don't have an unbiased estimator of $\bar{A}$.

Comment: But $\bar A$ is a random variable.

Comment: Maybe I should say $\bar{a}$ as after it's drawn, it's a constant. In any case, if my use of the term "bias" is in error, I'd be happy to know that but happier to understand how to prove that you need to double the variance.

Comment: You lost me at the first equation with "we know that."  If, as you write, you take a random sample $B$ of a population, then both the mean of $B$ and the mean of its complement $A$ have the same expectation, which equals the mean of the population.  Due to this, I cannot make sense of anything that follows.

Comment: I note that precise fact in the next line. Perhaps, I should change my notation to lower-case to clarify that I'm interested in a confidence interval that covers $\bar{a}$ 95 percent of the time?

Comment: You can construct a _prediction_ interval for $\bar A$ straightforwardly using the pivotal quantity $$
\frac{\bar B-\bar A}{S_B\sqrt{\frac1{n_A}+\frac1{n_B}}}\sim t_{n_B-1}
$$ as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, Tufto. Can you expand on this? Perhaps explaining how you get from here to an interval for $\bar{A}$ which is what I'm interested in?

Comment: Since the distribution of the above quantity is Student $t$, the quantity falls in-between the upper and lower $\alpha/2$-quantiles of the $t$ distribution with probability $1-\alpha$.  Then rearrange the double inequality to isolate $\bar A$ in the middle and you're done.

Comment: Does it make sense to speak of $E(\bar{B})$ as a biased estimator for $\bar{A}$ where this bias is the difference between $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$?

Comment: I suppose it makes sense to speak of $\bar B$ as a predictor of $\bar A$.  In contrast $E(\bar B)=\mu$ is not a function of the observed data but an unknown parameter assuming that all data points are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (which is required for what I said to be true).

Comment: If you’ve figured out the answer, it would be better to post a self-answer than to edit the answer into the original question. This way, the community can vote on your answer (which gives you an opportunity to correct mistakes, if you’ve made any), and the question can be “closed out”.

Answer (score 0):

As Jarle, points out above in a comment, the answer is simple. Assuming, iid data, for sufficiently large samples,

$$
\frac{\bar{A} - \bar{B}}{\sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2_A} {N_A} + \frac{\sigma^2_B} {N_B}  }} \approx N(0, 1)
$$

so we can construct the following 95 percent confidence interval for the difference in means.

$$
-1.96 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2_A} {N_A} + \frac{\sigma^2_B} {N_B}  } \le \bar{A} - \bar{B} \le 1.96 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2_A} {N_A} + \frac{\sigma^2_B} {N_B}  } 
$$

and then we add $\bar{B}$ to get the confidence interval for $\bar{A}$

$$
\bar{B} -1.96 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2_A} {N_A} + \frac{\sigma^2_B} {N_B}  } \le \bar{A} \le \bar{B} + 1.96 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2_A} {N_A} + \frac{\sigma^2_B} {N_B}  } 
$$

We can estimate $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_B$ by the sample variance of $B$.